# null pointer exception Java with drawing 2D array list

Tags: java, pointers, null

This might be a dumb question, but why am I getting a null pointer exception here?
I am trying to paint a tile map for a java applet. I just pasted the problem areas.

```
private int[][] map;     
public void init()
{
   int map[][]={ {0,0,0},
                {1,1,0},
                {0,0,0} };

}
public void drawCaveTiles(Graphics g)
{
   for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       for( int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
       {
           if(map[i][j] == 1)
           {
               g.drawImage(snow_brick, i*64, j*64, this);
           }
           if(map[i][j] == 0)
           {
               g.drawImage(black, i*64, j*64, this);
           }  
       }
    }

}
```

I fixed it

```
map =new int[][] { {0,0,0},
          {1,1,0},
          {0,0,0} };
```

Comment: After fixing the null pointer exception you have another logical problem in your code. The way you are using your loop variables `i` and `j` inside `drawImage` is wrong. `i` is the row of your array and therefore is the y coordinate and `j` is the column and so the x coordinate. If you already consider the difference between row, x coordinate and column, y coordinate by working with a transposed array see this comment as neglectable.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int map[][]={ {0,0,0},
                {1,1,0},
                {0,0,0} };
```

Here in the method `init()`, you are creating a new map which is local to the method `init()` and not initializing instance member `map`.

Change it to

```
   map ={ {0,0,0},
                {1,1,0},
                {0,0,0} };
```

And make sure you calling `inti()` method before calling  `drawCaveTiles()` method.

or Since it is a static data. Move that line to declaring place.

Answer (score 1):

In your `init()` method, you are hiding the class field `map`, because you are declaring it again (in the local block of the method `init()`).

Also, make sure you are calling the `init()` method. It should be called in your constructor:

```
public class YourApplet {
    public YourAppler() {
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
       map[][]={ {0,0,0},
                 {1,1,0},
                 {0,0,0} };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The local variable `int map[][]` in the `init()` is shadowing your instance variable `private int[][] map;`. Do not create a new local `int map` in the `init()` method. Just use the global map array in the `init()` method.

```
public void init() {
    map={ {0,0,0}, {1,1,0}, {0,0,0} };
}
```